# Is it possible to pull values from different fields into a rich text field of the same record?

Tags: richtextarea

I have a rich text field Work_Product__c on a custom object which I need to update with data from 'Name' field of the same record.
Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can not add formula as a default value.

  - You can write a trigger to update the text area value
  - You can use workflow field update as well
  - You can create a process using process builder

Let me know if you need more help.